# How to pull image from docker hub by Jenkins container

Tags: image, docker, jenkins, containers

I build a Jenkins container in docker, and I want to build a container(eg:ubuntu) from docker hub in Jenkins job, but it failed, the console output show failed pull from docker images `ubuntu:latest`, what problem in here?

please help me,thanks!!

here is console output:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pull_docker_image
Pull Docker image ubuntu:latest from repository ...
$ /var/jenkins_home/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool/docker/bin/docker pull ubuntu:latest
Failed to pull Docker image ubuntu:latest
--------------------------------------------------------
FATAL: Failed to pull Docker image ubuntu:latest
------------------------------------------------------------------
java.io.IOException: Failed to pull Docker image ubuntu:latest
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.PullDockerImageSelector.prepareDockerImage(PullDockerImageSelector.java:34)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.DockerBuildWrapper.setUp(DockerBuildWrapper.java:179)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:157)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

here is my configuration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abk6i.png)

Comment: Which jenkins plugin are you using for this?

Comment: @BimalVasan i use this "CloudBees Docker Custom Build Environment Plugin"

Answer (score 0):

when running the container which has jenkins, have you bound its docker.sock to the one of the hosting OS in order to run docker command from the jenkins container ?

```
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock JENKINS_IMAGE
```

If it is the solution of your problem, you might also need to /var/run/docker.sock with correct rights.

Let me know.